# Equalize sizes of quadtree cells

Tags: data-structures, graphics, quadtree, tessellation

A graphically represented quadtree is a tessellation of a square using  differently sized smaller squares. Is there a transformation that deforms the quadtree cells to achieve following 2 contrasting goals?

1. equalize the cell sizes by deforming them  (cell size is measured by area)
2. close cells in the original quadtree shall be close cells in the transformed result

The final result would be a deformed quadtree where all cell sizes are as similiar in area as possible while neighborhood relationship is maintained as good as possible. In ideal case one could weigh what is more important, equal area or neighborhood.

### Motivation

I have a 2d point cloud. To each point a value is associated. Geometrically close points have similar values but the gradient varies over the region. There are regions where the point values are quite constant and there are regions where the values of the points differ more with distance. The quadtree groups points of similar values, i.e. the degree of subdivision is high where the values of near points show large fluctuations. However this splitting of the original square results by definition  in differently sized cells. For further processing each cell shall be represented with equal size (=equal area). So I want to shrink larger cells and expand smaller cells and keep the neighborhood relationship. This is of course not possible without loosing some other properties. So one way would be to bend the plane in the 3rd dimension or to accept compromisses, i.e. cells are more equal sized than before and some neighborhood relationships are lost. I am looking for such a solution that deals with compromisses.

Centroidal Voronoi tessellation is not applicable. It leads to equally sized cells but doesn't care about neighborhood.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a homework completion service. At the very least, you could have paraphrased the darned question instead of just copying it from your assignment verbatim.

Comment: It's not a homework but a question at the brink of scientific knowledge. I couldn't try anything so far as I know no solution that fulfills the conditions.

Comment: Okay - sorry for the bad assumption. It reads like a homework question. :)

Comment: Homework asks for a known solution. In this case presumably no satisfactory solution exists.

Comment: The question as stated doesn't really contain anything requiring the "brink of scientific knowledge." If you want a quadtree with uniformly sized cells, make a quadtree with uniformly sized cells. Rebuilding the tree from scratch is likely the most efficient approach.

Comment: That's not always the case. I assign open-ended homework questions all the time. I'm typically as interested in the student's approach and thought process as I am in the actual solution. And I hate seeing copy-pasta plagiarism in submissions since I then have to fill out paperwork and refer the student to the honor committee.

Comment: The cells are not of equal area if presented graphically. This is the starting point. To subdivide equally everywhere as recommended in the previous comment results in a different quadtree.

Comment: A motivation was added. Is it now understandable?

Comment: Does it need to be a quadtree? R-Trees already do a similar 'grouping', they also ensure that the tree has (almost) everywhere the same depth.

Comment: R tree  tessellates space with overlapping cells. Not applicable.